# PowerPoint 2010 not showing slides full screen

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

Recently I was showing a presentation in PP 2010 when I noticed that the slides were no longer showing full screen (either on my laptop or on the projector), but had wide black margins each side.

It seems that some setting has changed on my laptop as when I write a new presentation and show that the same thing happens.

Does anyone have any clues as to what has happened? It was working fine during the morning and then in the afternoon the slides suddenly changed.

Thanks in advance.

Jenny

Answer (score 4):

Check the aspect ratio of your PowerPoint presentation. It sounds like your laptop and projector are using a widescreen resolution (16:10 or 16:9), but the presentation is set up for a non-widescreen display (4:3).

To change the presentation's aspect ratio, go to the **Design** tab, click on **Page Setup** and select the correct aspect ratio from the "Slides sized for" dropdown menu

Comment: Thanks. This slideshow was fine and then changed during the presentation. I have tried the various resolutions but lose the bottom and top of the slides. Might it be something to do with the connection to the projector? I had some difficulties with the cable which kept falling out due to awkward positioning.